# how to make gnome use my home folder as Desktop folder?

Tags: directory, home, freedesktop

Environment: Debian 7, gnome-shell.

I dislike having a Desktop folder and a Home folder. I like all the applications to use my home folder. Specifically I am concerned about `nautilus` and `gnome-terminal`.

I set nautilus to use Home as Desktop using `dconf-editor` and property `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.desktop-is-home-dir==true`.

That works well.

But when I launch a `gnome-terminal` it starts a shell at `/home/username/Desktop`. That is highly annoying because I do not use that dir.

I am sure that my home dir is properly set:

```
$ grep username /etc/passwd
username:x:1000:1000:username,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash
$ echo $HOME
/home/username
```

how can I change that behavior so the shell starts at `/home/username`?

Comment: I am using the default gnome-shell that comes with debian stable. For me stability and resiliency are way way more valuable than features. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Not sure if you can/want to promote it to an answer so you can take credit for it, but it sure is a valid answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually want to disable the `Desktop` directory and prevent the DE to automatically recreate it.

Short answer:
Edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and change `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` value to `$HOME`:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"
```

Long answer:
**How to disable/relocate the User Directories (Desktop, Pictures, Documents etc) ?**

On a `freedesktop` compliant DE this is done via the `XDG` user directories configuration file, namely `$(XDG_CONFIG_HOME)/user-dirs.dirs`:

> $(XDG_CONFIG_HOME)/user-dirs.dirs specifies the current set of
>   directories for the user.

If not set or empty, [`XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defaults to `~/.config`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) so, for most users, the file in question is `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Applications read this file to find those directories. The file consists of `key=value` pairs, one per line.
The default locations are:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/.Templates"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

**To relocate a certain directory** edit the config file and replace the current value with the location of your choice, e.g.

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/run/media/mybackupdrive/documents"
```

**To disable a certain directory** point it to the home directory:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"
```

For those who prefer a CLI tool, XDG provides [xdg-user-dirs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/):

Relocate VIDEOS:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set VIDEOS /media/bkdrive/myvideos
```

Query current location for VIDEOS:

```
xdg-user-dir VIDEOS

/media/bkdrive/myvideos
```

Note:
*After* configuring `user-dirs.dirs`, if some User Dirs are on drives that are not accessible at startup you might want to disable `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` (if present on your system), i.e.  edit the `enabled` line to read:

```
enabled=False
```

see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1458706) discussion for more details.