# symlink /home/username/Documenten tot 2nd partition?

Tags: filenames, symlink, ln

I am trying to make a symlink so all documents are on a different harddisk drive.
I learned how to make a symlink and tried to create the desired symlink.
this is the command I used in terminal:

`ln -s /media/Schijf-2/Nel/Mijn Documenten/ ./home/nel/Documenten`

However, I receive an error message:

`ln: target '.home/username/Documenten' is not a directory`

I found similar questions but I do not understand what I did wrong:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/465493/how-can-i-symlink-my-home-folder-from-another-drive

[Create a symbolic link relative to the current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory)

I tried to symlink my `/home/<user>/Documenten` directory to `/media/Schijf-2/Nel/Mijn Documenten`.

How can I succeed?

Comment: Actually, I suspect your problem is the initial period -- `./home/nel/Documenten` starts from the *current* directory rather than the filesystem root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your command. You ran

```
ln -s /media/Schijf-2/Nel/Mijn Documenten/ ./home/nel/Documenten
```

This means "create a link called `Documenten` that points to `/media/Schijf-2/Nel/Mijn Documenten/`. Because of the space, the ln command was given `Documenten` and not `./home/nel/Documenten` as a target. One of way of dealing with this is to quote the name (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222) for more information):

```
ln -s /media/Schijf-2/Nel/"Mijn Documenten"/ ./home/nel/Documenten
```

The next issue is that apparently, there is already a file (and not a directory) called `Documenten` in your current directory which is why `ln` complains:

```
$ ls
file.txt
$ ln -s /tmp/ ./file.txt/
ln: target ‘./file.txt/’ is not a directory: Not a directory
```

So, to do what you actually wanted to do you will need to delete or rename the `Documenten` file:

```
$ mv Documenten Documenten.old
```

Then, run this command to create a link:

```
$ ln -s /media/Schijf-2/Nel/"Mijn Documenten"/ Documenten
```

Comment: Can it be a problem that the /home/<user>/Documenten directory is a standard directory which is install automatically when a user is added?

Comment: @DutchArjo I don't see why, no. It should make no difference as long as the directory (or a link to a directory) exists.

Comment: @DutchArjo - the proper way to relocate `User Dirs` (e.g. Documents, Pictures etc) is via the config file [`user-dirs.dirs`, see here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167833/22142).

Comment: thanks. That is exactly what I wanted to do indeed! When you would post that as an answer, I can accept it...

Comment: @terdon thanks, I now have succeeded in creating the symlink. I did not understand that I had to be in the /home directory to create a symlink to a different location there. I now have the symlink, and 'cd-in' into this symlink brings me exactly to the right location.

Comment: @DutchArjo glad to be of help. What did you want me to post for you to accept this? Also, don_crissti has a point, it might be better to just change the location of the default directory as explained in the link he gave.

Comment: sorry, I see I forgot to mention @don_crissti in my comment. I wanted to use his suggestion and accept is as the used answer (I have used his suggestion now, although I ran into some other problem). Can I accept 2 answers? Yours becuase it learned me to create a proper symlink and don_crissti's answer to have the best way to relocate my default directory's. But I believe I should both the suggestions... (the symlink from documents, or downloads, because I have changed the xdg user dirs file now but the Downloads directory in Home does not refer to mijn /media/schijf-2 partition

Comment: @DutchArjo no, you can only accept one but feel free to accept don_crissti's if he posts it.